# ExtJs3 how to add spinner textbox

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have text box that can be enter value (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). I can convert to textbox using Jquery but that is conflict with my some of JS library So I want to convert that text box to spinner using ExtJs3 how can i do? please give some example code how will i convert textbox as spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `textfield` component you can use `Ext.ux.form.SpinnerField` extension. This extension is bundled in ExtJs 3.4 library in `examples/ux` folder.

Live example you can find here: http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/3.4.1.1/examples/spinner/spinner.html

So if you want step by 1 and do not allowed negative values, your `spinnerfield` config should be:

```
{
    xtype: 'spinnerfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Test',
    name: 'test',
    minValue: 0,
    allowDecimals: false,
    incrementValue: 1,
    accelerate: true
}
```

Comment: Yes, this extension exists also in 3.2 release.